# NodeJs :- Getting "missing credentials" error while using local passport

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, passport.js, bcrypt

I was trying to implement a functionality where a user can reset a password. I have tried the below code and while I am not getting any error, its not updating the password. The password is the same ie the old password.

my User model file is as follows:-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

const LoginUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
    resetPasswordToken: String,
    resetPasswordExpires: Date
});

// The below is used so as to allow passport to reset password
LoginUserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose);

const LoginUser = mongoose.model('LoginUser', LoginUserSchema);

module.exports = LoginUser;
```

My routes file is as follows:-

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
const passport = require('passport');
var async = require("async");
// Load User model
const User = require('../models/loginuser');
var nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
var crypto = require("crypto");
// Load Auth from files
const { ensureAuthenticated, forwardAuthenticated } = require('../config/auth');

// Login Page
router.get('/login', forwardAuthenticated, (req, res) => res.render('login'));

// Register Page
router.get('/register', (req, res) =>{
  if(typeof req.user == "undefined"){
    console.log("HERE IT IS");
    res.redirect('/users/login');
  }
  if (req.user.email == "theamarex@gmail.com"){
  res.render('register')
  }else{
    res.redirect('/users/login');
  }
})

// Register
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {

  const { name, email, password, password2 } = req.body;
  let errors = [];

  if (!name || !email || !password || !password2) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Please enter all fields' });
  }

  if (password != password2) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Passwords do not match' });
  }

  if (password.length < 6) {
    errors.push({ msg: 'Password must be at least 6 characters' });
  }

  if (errors.length > 0) {
    res.render('register', {
      errors,
      name,
      email,
      password,
      password2
    });
  } else {
    User.findOne({ email: email }).then(user => {
      if (user) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Email already exists' });
        res.render('register', {
          errors,
          name,
          email,
          password,
          password2
        });
      } else {
        const newUser = new User({
          name,
          email,
          password
        });

        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
          bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            newUser.password = hash;
            newUser
              .save()
              .then(user => {
                req.flash(
                  'success_msg',
                  'You are now registered and can log in'
                );
                res.redirect('/users/login');
              })
              .catch(err => console.log(err));
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }
});

// Login
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/users/dashboard',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: true
  })(req, res, next);
});

// Logout
router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
  req.logout();
  req.flash('success_msg', 'You are logged out');
  res.redirect('/users/login');
});

// Dashboard
router.get('/dashboard', ensureAuthenticated, (req, res) =>{
  res.render('dashboard', {
    user: req.user
  })
}
);

// Forgot password url
router.get('/forgot', function(req, res) {
  res.render('forgot');
});

router.post('/forgot', function(req, res, next) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
        var token = buf.toString('hex');
        done(err, token);
      });
    },
    function(token, done) {
      User.findOne({ email: req.body.email }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'No account with that email address exists.');
          return res.redirect('/users/forgot');
        }

        user.resetPasswordToken = token;
        user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

        user.save(function(err) {
          done(err, token, user);
        });
      });
    },
    function(token, user, done) {
      var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: 'Gmail', 
        auth: {
          user: '',
          pass: ''
        }
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        //to: user.email,
        to: "cechque@gmail.com",
        from: 'theamarexrouting@gmail.com',
        subject: 'Node.js Password Reset',
        text: 'You are receiving this because you (or someone else) have requested the reset of the password for your account.\n\n' +
          'Please click on the following link, or paste this into your browser to complete the process:\n\n' +
          'http://' + req.headers.host + '/users/reset/' + token + '\n\n' +
          'If you did not request this, please ignore this email and your password will remain unchanged.\n'
      };
      smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        console.log('mail sent');
        req.flash('success', 'An e-mail has been sent to ' + user.email + ' with further instructions.');
        done(err, 'done');
      });
    }
  ], function(err) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    res.redirect('/users/forgot');
  });
});

// Reset password url
router.get('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
  User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
    if (!user) {
      req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
      return res.redirect('/forgot');
    }
    res.render('reset', {token: req.params.token});
  });
});



 router.post('/reset/:token', function(req, res) {
  async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
          return res.redirect('back');
        }
        if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm) {
            user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
            user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;
            user.password = req.body.password;

          bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
              if (err) throw err;
              user.password = hash;
                user.save(function(err) {
                  req.login(user, function(err) {
                    console.log(user);
                    done(err, user);
                  });
                });
            });
          });
        } else {
            req.flash("error", "Passwords do not match.");
            return res.redirect('back');
        }
      });
    },
        function(user, done) {
          var smtpTransport = nodemailer.createTransport({
            service: 'Gmail', 
            auth: {
              user: '',
              pass: ''
            }
          });
          var mailOptions = {
            to: "",
            from: '',
            subject: 'Your password has been changed',
            text: 'Hello,\n\n' +
              'This is a confirmation that the password for your account ' + user.email + ' has just been changed.\n'
          };
          smtpTransport.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
            req.flash('success', 'Success! Your password has been changed.');
            done(err);
          });
        }
      ], function(err) {
        res.redirect('/users/dashboard');
      });
    });


    module.exports = router;
```

I am a bit confused where I have gone wrong. I tried to search various answers online and on this forum but it didn't help me out. Please help me out. Thanks

Comment: Looks like there is a mismatch on where the password is stored - upon user account creation, `password` field is populated manually, but for password change `passport-local-mongoose` is used for password change (via `setPassword`) - the latter uses `hash` field by default to store the password hash, and looks like this is not overriden (no `hashField` configuration option is provided).

Comment: @SergeyLapin can you recommend any changes in the code or how do i go forward with this. Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest to have a common procedure to generate password in both cases - by either dropping the whole logic around bcrypt when creating an account and just letting `passport-local-mongoose` do it's job. Otherwise, you could drop `passport-local-mongoose` instead and then just manually generate and assign a new password hash to the user (instead of calling `setPassword`) - the same way it's done in `POST /register`.

Comment: @SergeyLapin I did what you recommended and manually generated and assigned a new password hash to the user but I am getting "missing credentials" error.

Comment: does "missing credentials" error happen when you try to login after changing password? If so, is it possible to log in with a fresh account before its password is changed?

Comment: @SergeyLapin geting an error while login with a fresh account before changing the password as well. Updated my question.

Comment: it looks clearer after you latest update. In the latest state, `passport-local-mongoose` is used for neither account creation nor password reset, but is still used for login. Continuing that way, you should drop `passport.authenticate` from `POST /login` and replace it with manual procedure: taking password passport.authenticate in the body and salt from user document, calculate the hash and compare with hash from user document. Create session when equals, redirect fo /login if not. Or, still rely on `passport-local-mongoose` in all 3 cases.

Comment: @SergeyLapin Thanks for the help. I changed my code and its now working as required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have made changes to the code. You have used `passport-local-mongoose` wrongly here.

```
   //register    
    if (errors.length > 0) {
              res.render('register', {
                errors,
                name,
                username,
                password,
                password2
              });
            } else {
              User.findOne({ username: username }).then(user => {
                if (user) {
                  errors.push({ msg: 'username already exists' });
                  res.render('register', {
                    errors,
                    name,
                    username,
                    password,
                    password2
                  });
                } else {
                  const newUser = new User({
                  name,
                  username,
                  password
                  });

                  User.register(newUser, req.body.password, function(err, user){
                      console.log(req.body)
                      if(err){
                          console.log(err);
                          return res.render("register", {error: err.message});
                      }
                      passport.authenticate("local")(req, res, function(){
                      req.flash("success", "Successfully Signed Up! Nice to meet you " + req.body.name);
                      res.redirect('/users/login');
                      });
                  });
                }
              });
            }

    // forgot password

    router.post('/forgot', function(req, res, next) {
      async.waterfall([
        function(done) {
          crypto.randomBytes(20, function(err, buf) {
            var token = buf.toString('hex');
            done(err, token);
          });
        },
        function(token, done) {
          User.findOne({ username: req.body.username }, function(err, user) {
            if (!user) {
              req.flash('error', 'No account with that username address exists.');
              return res.redirect('/users/forgot');
            }

            user.resetPasswordToken = token;
            user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

            user.save(function(err) {
              done(err, token, user);
            });
          });
        },

//reset token
async.waterfall([
    function(done) {
      User.findOne({ resetPasswordToken: req.params.token, resetPasswordExpires: { $gt: Date.now() } }, function(err, user) {
        if (!user) {
          req.flash('error', 'Password reset token is invalid or has expired.');
          return res.redirect('back');
        }
        if(req.body.password === req.body.confirm) {
          user.setPassword(req.body.password, function(err) {
            user.resetPasswordToken = undefined;
            user.resetPasswordExpires = undefined;

            user.save(function(err) {
              req.logIn(user, function(err) {
                done(err, user);
              });
            });
          })
        } else {
            req.flash("error", "Passwords do not match.");
            return res.redirect('back');
        }
      });
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

I got a changepassword route using passport. Maybe its useful for you. Here it is:

```
router.post('/changepassword', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    User.findOne({ username: req.user.username })
        .then(user => {
            if (!user) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    success: false
                });
            } else if (req.body.password !== req.body.confirm_password) {
                return res.status(404).json({
                    msg: "Wachtwoorden komen niet overeen",
                    success: false
                });
            }
            bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
                bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                    user.password = hash;
                    user.save().then(user => {
                        return res.status(201).json({
                            success: true,
                            msg: "Wachtwoord veranderd"
                        });
                    })
                });
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        })
})
```